# JQuery slideToggle only appears if window resized [Chrome?]

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, resize, slidetoggle

First time poster and amateur programmer here - basically my JQuery is exhibiting very strange behavior for what I would have assumed was a simple script;

Basically want a button that on click toggles a full width flexslider underneath. When clicked it looks like nothing appears (although Dev Tools tells me that the div has the display:none removed) - then I resize the window and BAM! It's there?

On Safari there's another problem but it is unrelated to this (I assume?)

The site itself is on WordPress - I have inherited this as part of a new job, I have some knowledge of HTML, CSS and rudimentary JS. Please help!

```js
/* Creative Slider 1 - OLD CODE */
$('.creativebutton1').on('click', function() {
  $('.creative-content1').slideToggle('slow');
});

/*NEW CODE */

$('.creativebutton1').on('click', function(){
 $('.creative-content1').slideToggle('slow');
 $('.create-slider').flexslider({
 animation: "slide",
 directionNav: true, 
 controlNav: false,
 animationSpeed: 1000,
 selector: '.slides > .slide-group',
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <a id="servicecontent"></a>
    <div class="block dark-grey-bg">
      <div class="content-container container">
        <div class="block-icon bounceInLeft wow animated" style="visibility: visible;">
          <img src="http://www.placeholder.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/service-icon-paintbrush.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1> Header &amp; Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="block-text">
          <p><span class="light-blue-text"><strong></strong></span> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
          <p><span class="light-blue-text"><strong>SubHead </strong></span>&nbsp;– Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .</p>
          <p><span class="light-blue-text"><strong>SubHead</strong></span> – Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .</p>
          <p><span class="light-blue-text"><strong>SubHead</strong></span> – Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .</p>
          <p><span class="light-blue-text"><strong>SubHead</strong></span> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .</p>
          <div class="button blue-button creativebutton1 learn-more wow bounceInLeft animated" style="visibility: visible;"><a href="#creative-content1">See Examples</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ################# SLIDER TIME #################-->
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="creative-content1" style="display: none;">
      <div class="flexslider create-slider">
        <div class="slides">
          <div class="slide-group">
            <div class="createslide">
              <img src="http://www.placeholder.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slide1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-group">
            <div class="createslide">
              <img src="http://www.placeholder.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slide2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-group">
            <div class="createslide">
              <img src="http://www.placeholder.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slide3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like got a few things going on here. First it seems that your jQuery may not be "ready". Wrap your current function into a:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  YOUR CODE
});
```

Check out the docs [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Next up is that the function, as written, is not a valid function, for the version of jQuery being used.

I went about changing your jQuery function to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.creativebutton1').click(function() {
    $('.creative-content1').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the function you have, simply wrap it in a `$(document).ready` and change the version of jQuery to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! The actual code is part of a site custom js anyway inside a document ready (I believe) - but whilst looking at this I managed to solve the issue - I initialised the slider on the click of the button as well as the slide toggle and it works flawlessly now!